# Cannot find the Syntax Error for CodeCademy JavaScript Lesson 32/33

Tags: javascript

I am working on a JavaScript program of [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/) and have a simple assignment to create a new object using the Constructor 'book'. I keep getting an error for the author but I cannot understand why.

```
// 3 lines required to make harry_potter
var harry_potter = new Object();
harry_potter.pages = 350;
harry_potter.author = "J.K. Rowling";

// A custom constructor for book
function Book (pages, author) {
    this.pages = pages;
    this.author = author;
};

// Use our new constructor to make the_hobbit in one line
var the_hobbit = new Book(320, "J.R.R Tolkien") ;
```

Comment: You haven't defined what pages and author are? you need to assign pages as an Int and author as a string.

Comment: not for javascript @BIW

Comment: How did you get this far and not know what the problem is?

Comment: "I keep getting an error" --- any particular reason you did not put that error in the question?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious in there

Comment: It is actually the correct solution, so this must be an issue with codeacademy, which happens from time to time. I did this course a while ago and checked my solution for this question, which was identical, and works @AustinHansen

Comment: "Oops, try again. Make sure that the_hobbit's author is J.R.R. Tolkien by passing it as the first argument to the Book constructor." is the error I receive. I was worried it would be misleading because if you try to change the Constructor that is prewritten to put author as the first argument you get the error "
Oops, try again. Please do not modify the Book constructor!"

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Thank you. I wonder what I should do then? just skip it?

Comment: You did not set the author to `"J.R.R. Tolkien"`

Comment: @AustinHansen you need to add an extra full stop after the ```R``` in ```J.R.R.```

Comment: @zerkms how do you mean? the last part of the code should assign author the value of "J.R.R. Tolkien" right?

Comment: you are missing one full stop. if you add that it will work @zerkms is right

Comment: an extra period? i tried that and no luck actually

Comment: Try taking off the semi-colon from the book function and get rid of the white space between the last semicolon and params. Could just be a parse error on their side.

Comment: Provide the whole codeacademy task description.

Comment: use the exact code I provided below and it will work @AustinHansen

Comment: how do i mark this as answered and closed? im sorry still new to SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the error message:

> Oops, try again. Make sure that the_hobbit's author is "J.R.R. Tolkien" by passing it as the first argument to the Book constructor.

which means you simply lost one dot character in your code:

```
var the_hobbit = new Book(320, "J.R.R Tolkien") ;
                                     ^-- here should be an extra dot
```